# CSS Button hover not working

Tags: css, hover

this should be an easy one for most of you but I can't get my head round it. I've got the code below for my buttons but I can't seem to get the hover working even though the buttons are styled correctly:

```
.eventmark .upcomming_bg {
background: #1178bd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1178bd, #0c3c5c);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1178bd, #0c3c5c);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1178bd, #0c3c5c);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1178bd, #0c3c5c);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1178bd, #0c3c5c);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.eventmark.upcoming.bg:hover{
 background: #3d7a80;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
 background: linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo error:corrected at 2 places

```
.eventmark.upcomming.bg {
  background: #1178bd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1178bd, #0c3c5c);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1178bd, #0c3c5c);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1178bd, #0c3c5c);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1178bd, #0c3c5c);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1178bd, #0c3c5c);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.eventmark.upcomming.bg:hover{
 background: #3d7a80;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
 background: linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a space between your two classes in the first code block, but not in the second code block.  So, the selector is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
eventmark.upcoming.bg
```

You sure about no spaces in there? That would equate to

```
<div class="eventmark upcoming bg">
```

All classes assigned to same element.